# jwplayer cannot seek video of google photo

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, google-photos

I upload a video to google photo.
I use jwplayer to play video. but I can't seek video.
When I click to seek video, video is replay with start time 00:00.

This is my code

```js
player = jwplayer("apicodes-player");
    player.setup({
        playlist: [
            { sources: [{
                  label: "360p",
                  type: "video/mp4",
                  file: "https://video-downloads.googleusercontent.com/AMfe5wrawK220JrFOrFTfUGIbTtgk_MNzkCa3xGjrNyqCPODbSRcnm8JYAginZRK3VRcEM46ogfCAQzG2n3aly0zn9JQKy0mWx5z1YeNfwsIlUZwh-w_UeTV1xfBiRj6Wt246t5xt1m_lEoL6Ed5W8vptAG4t-3QhG5jqFTdNMJUZWsX8vaBeW_AxM0LGYtihXYZm9r-7aki"
            }]},
        ],
        aspectratio: "16:9",
        startparam: "start",
        primary: "html5",
        ga: {},
        playbackRateControls: true,
        autostart: false,
        preload: "auto"
});
```

I tried demo with https://www.jwplayer.com/developers/player-event-inspector/ but it doesn't not working with seek and rewind.
Json input test is:

```
{
    playlist: [{
        sources: [{
            label: "360p",
            type: "video/mp4",
            file: "https://video-downloads.googleusercontent.com/AMfe5wrawK220JrFOrFTfUGIbTtgk_MNzkCa3xGjrNyqCPODbSRcnm8JYAginZRK3VRcEM46ogfCAQzG2n3aly0zn9JQKy0mWx5z1YeNfwsIlUZwh-w_UeTV1xfBiRj6Wt246t5xt1m_lEoL6Ed5W8vptAG4t-3QhG5jqFTdNMJUZWsX8vaBeW_AxM0LGYtihXYZm9r-7aki"
        }]
    }, ],
    "width": "50%",
    "aspectratio": "16:9",
    "autostart": false,
    "controls": true,
    "preload": "metadata",
    "primary": "html5"
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using the "Google Photo API" in some measure somewhere? Likely the link you are using was authenticated but very different script, but your code does not have auth so the Google server rejects the request? Sounds likely.

Comment: Video play well. It just doesn't seek or rewind.

Comment: Have you been able to seek and rewind on local videos in your test environment?

Comment: I tested in localhost and real domain.

Comment: What happens if you just treat it as a HTML5 video without the jwplayer? I suppose that might be a stretch. Have you checked the dev-tools of your test browser to inspect the errors/warnings?

Comment: I also tested on https://www.jwplayer.com/developers/player-event-inspector/, but doesn't work with seed and rewind. I just updated post, you can see my demo.

Comment: I just want to ask how do you get that url of the video? I just found some piracy websites used the same url type and I want to find out how to use that url or find that url *video-downloads.googleusercontent.com*

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think this is because the Google Photos server does not support partial content responses. See [HTML5 Video Tag in Chrome - Why is currentTime ignored when video downloaded from my webserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572720/html5-video-tag-in-chrome-why-is-currenttime-ignored-when-video-downloaded-fro) and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111931138.

One option would be to download the video from your server and control de streaming yourself.